# CSS Named grid fragmented, same named areas not joined

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have read MDN docs, and SO answers. They stress that named areas in CSS grids must be continguous, and rectangular. My grid below follows these requirements, however the icon named area does not fill 2 cells, only 1:
HTML:

```html
<label for="js-icon" class="OfficeIconField">
  <input id="js-icon" class="OfficeFloatInput" value="" type="text" required="" placeholder="Placeholder text">
  <label for="js-icon" class="OfficeFloatLabel js-css-blank">Text placeholder</label>
  <span class="OfficeHelp">Some help text</span>
  <svg class="OfficeIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px" fill="black" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="m12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"></path>
</svg>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.OfficeIconField {
    display: grid;
    gap: 8px;
    align-items: end;
    grid-template-columns: 64px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "icon label"
      "icon input"
      "blank help";
    & .OfficeFloatLabel {
        grid-area: label;
    }
    & .OfficeFloatInput {
        grid-area: input;
    }
    & .OfficeHelp {
        grid-area: help;
    }
    & .OfficeIcon {
        grid-area: icon;
        background: red !important;
        justify-self: center;
    }
}
```

Result (you can see `.OfficeIcon` only spans the top left cell, instead of being merged with the cell below it too:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

How to fix the named area to span 2 cells?

And position it at the bottom center of its cell like this:
[image]

Im guessing I am going to have to place the SVG within a `div`, and then position the SVG inside the `div`. I would prefer to do it without the extra `div` if possible.

Comment: try height:100% and width:100%

Comment: I'd also remove this from the SVG `width="32px" height="32px"`

Comment: height:100% and width:100% on `.OfficeIcon` makes it fill the `blank` area too, so weird.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right, its the SVG size messing it up. This is my first time using CSS named grids, so I thought something else was at play, but replacing it for normal diff works. Its weird than Chrome paints a gutter then in the merged cell, incorrectly making it look like its two cells.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for spotting that. I deleted some pseudo selector cases to make the question clearly, but missed that, corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make grid columns with `grid-template-columns: 64px 1fr;` , so try to just adjust svg size to 64px, or you can use `align-self: end;` and `justify-self: center;` on `.OfficeIcon`

```css
.OfficeIconField {
    display: grid;
    gap: 8px;
    grid-template-columns: 64px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "icon label"
      "icon input"
      "blank help";
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
.OfficeFloatLabel {
        grid-area: label;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
.OfficeFloatInput {
        grid-area: input;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
.OfficeHelp {
        grid-area: help;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
.OfficeIcon {
        grid-area: icon;
        background: red !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
        align-self: end;
        justify-self: center;
        /*align-self: stretch; /* desperate attempt */*/
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="js-icon" class="OfficeIconField">
  <input id="js-icon" class="OfficeFloatInput" value="" type="text" required="" placeholder="Placeholder text">
  <label for="js-icon" class="OfficeFloatLabel js-css-blank">Text placeholder</label>
  <span class="OfficeHelp">Some help text</span>
  <svg class="OfficeIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px" fill="black" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    <path d="m12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"></path>
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a big issue of why I wish to merge the cells, is that the icon can be positioned at the bottom. Sorry for the ambiguity, I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Your code pen runs well, thank you. I am trying to apply it to my code to make it work, but I am running into some troubles, but I think this will be the accepted answer, just testing it abit more, it should work.